# sql routines vs events

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database and I want to execute UPDATE and TRUNCATE queries every 24 hours. I have seen that I cannot combine the SQL statements into one event which will be easier than having multiple events.

[image]

I am using phpMyAdmin and would like help implementing the following statements every 24 hours.

```html
 
TRUNCATE online_mentions; 
TRUNCATE online_messages; 
TRUNCATE user_views;
 
UPDATE forgot_password SET counter = 0; 
UPDATE meta_tags SET views_daily = 0; 
UPDATE post_tags SET daily=0; 
UPDATE user_count SET views_daily = 0, followers_daily = 0, following_daily = 0, pages_daily = 0, logins_daily = 0; 
UPDATE user_settings SET name = 0, password = 0, image = 0, questions = 0;
 
UPDATE xtrack_user_bio SET status_daily = 0, deletes_daily = 0, relationship_daily = 0; 
UPDATE xtrack_user_chats SET chats_daily = 0, refresh_daily = 0, myChats_daily = 0, myMentions_daily = 0, men_daily = 0, women_daily = 0; 
UPDATE xtrack_user_comments SET comments_daily = 0, edits_daily = 0, likes_daily = 0, dislikes_daily = 0, flags_daily = 0, deletes_daily = 0 ; 
UPDATE xtrack_user_messages SET messages_daily = 0, refresh_daily = 0, flags_daily = 0, single_deletes_daily = 0, all_deletes_daily = 0; 
UPDATE xtrack_user_posts SET posts_daily = 0, edits_daily = 0, likes_daily = 0, dislikes_daily = 0, flags_daily = 0, saves_daily = 0, deletes_daily = 0 ; 
UPDATE xtrack_user_reports SET general_daily = 0, user_daily = 0, website_daily = 0; 
UPDATE xtrack_user_settings SET username = 0, password = 0, image = 0, questions = 0;
```

Comment: You have added the PHP tag to your question. Does this mean you plan to implement this in PHP? What have you tried? Which problem did you encounter?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sorry the PHP tag was accidental, anyway I have edited the question to show the error I get when trying to have multiple statements in on event. I am not good with routines either and don't quite understand how to implement them properly

Comment: The query that generates the error is not present in your question. I assume that is intentional, but it could be helpful if it was included. It would also show that you tried something, and that's a positive thing. Try to include textual information as text, not as an image. We can edit text, not images.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the error is that I cannot combine multiple statements into an event, the statements are otherwise fine. I am looking for an alternative way of executing the all of the statements without an SQL event

Comment: You haven't specified the environment. But normally you would put multiple statements in a text file and simply run that file in MySQL. That can be done in PHPMyAdmin by importing that file. You could use a [cron job](https://ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/) to run the file every 24 hours if you're using linux.

Comment: If you want to keep the scheduled event, you could try to work with `SOURCE <file>`. See: [Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html). I haven't tested this.

Comment: Did you set delimiters?

Comment: 'When you create an event, you are creating a named database object containing one or more SQL statements to be executed at one or more regular intervals' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html so multiple statements is not your problem.

Comment: You would need to use `BEGIN .... END` for [Compound Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you BEGIN .. END works just fine. I don't know why the END line shows a red cross though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by adding `BEGIN ... END`

```html
BEGIN
TRUNCATE table_name; 
TRUNCATE table_name; 
TRUNCATE table_name;
END
```

Comment: Nice you know you solved it in the end.